# How to get the same PHP adler32 hash in Python?

Tags: php, python, hash

I need to produce the same adler32 hash which is generated by PHP, but using Python. Unfortunately the standard implementations differ. Any ideas?

```
$ php -r 'print hash("adler32", "bla") . "\n";'
02620130

$ python -c 'import zlib; print zlib.adler32("bla");'
39977264
```

(Am using PHP 5.5.9 and Python 2.7.6)

At the moment I've resorted to

```
def php_adler32(string):
    phpcode = """print hash("adler32", "%s");""" % string
    try:
        rv = subprocess.check_output(['php','-r',phpcode], shell=False)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        raise RuntimeError("Could not compute adler32 through php: %s" % e)
    return rv
```

But I am afraid to end up on dailywtf.com with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, pyton is giving a result in decimal and PHP is giving your the result in hex. So converting like so:

```
php -r 'print hexdec(hash("adler32", "bla")) . "\n";'
```

should give you a result which agrees with python.

Longer answer

The adler 32 rolling hash consists of an A and B value. The A-value starts at one and adds on the value of the character modulo 65521. The B-value starts at zero and adds on the current A-value modulo 65521, so for bla we have:

```
Character Decimal Adler_A Adler_B
                        1       0
      'b'      98      99      99
      'l'     108      207    306
      'a'      97      304    610
```

So the final adler32 A and B values of the whole string are `Adler_A = 304` and `Adler_B = 610`, which when converted to big-endian hex is `Adler_A = 0130` and `Adler_B = 0262`. So you can see that PHP's hash is giving you a big-endian representation of Adler_B followed by Adler_A, `01300262`. Converting this hex value to decimal gives `39977264`, which is what you were getting from python.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, this is equiv for PHP: `"%08d" % int(hex(adler32('bla'))[2:]`

Answer (score 1):

From looking around, I believe the PHP implementation is returning incorrect values. (https://github.com/Sembiance/mhash/issues/6)

When testing with the older mhash library used by PHP (now deprecated by hash), we can see the same result as the current hash library.

```
define('MOD_ADLER', 65521);
// Wikipedia Implimentation for testing.
function adler32($data) {
    $a = 1; 
    $b = 0; 
    $len = strlen($data);
    for ($index = 0; $index < $len; ++$index) {
        $a = ($a + $data[$index]) % MOD_ADLER;
        $b = ($b + $a) % MOD_ADLER;
    }
    return ($b << 16) | $a;
}
echo "programed version: " . adler32("bla") . "<br>";
echo "php version: " . hash("adler32", "bla") . "<br>";
echo "mhash version: " .bin2hex(mhash(MHASH_ADLER32, "bla"));
```

The end result became this:

```
programed version: 196609 (I'm not quite sure why this occured to be honest)
php version: 02620130
mhash version: 02620130
```

We can see that the PHP (hash) and mash versions produce the same results, albeit the mhash function returns a hexadecimal number.

The zlib python results would prove to be the most reliable in terms of their output.